# Handling default language in jquery-localize

Tags: javascript, localization

I'm trying to use jquery-localize for localization of my small app. My wish is to use Danish language if the user is Danish, and English otherwise.

I tried doing nothing, but if an unknown language uses the app, then all strings are empty.

My current solution is this

```
chosenLanguage = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
langSearch = new RegExp('^da', 'i');
if (chosenLanguage.match(langSearch)){
  // Do nothing
}
else {
  $("[data-localize]").localize("local", { language: "en" });
}
```

But this solution seems too complex to be correct. Any help or suggestions is appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by jquery-localize?

Comment: @jukka-k-korpela Sorry... I forgot the link [link](https://github.com/coderifous/jquery-localize)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jquery-localize library appears to be rather pritimive string customization tool, without even an idea of a fallback to a generic locale. Your current solution, too, is too simple rather than too complex. It relies on “browser language”, which need not have anything to do with the user’s language preferences. Instead, design and implement language switching. The usual way is to make the English version primary and provide some links or buttons for changing to other language(s).

Comment: Any tips on libraries or best practices?

Comment: @angak, in the simple scenario, you would have the page initially in English (you could do that using the `localize` function) and it would contain a button that calls the `localize` function to translate into Danish.